# Combining two lists of data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below variables:

```
info_list = [("class1", "student1"), ("class1", "student2"), ("class2", "student1")]
dataframe_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

each `dfN` looks like below:

df1:

```
A   B
10  20
23  31
```

df2:

```
A   B
2   9
11  51
60  89
```

df3:

```
A   B
1   2
3   9
```

I want to match the nth info_list element to nth data frame of dataframe_list and then concatenate the data frames to one. 
Below is my desired dataframe:

```
class   student   A   B
class1  student1  10  20
class1  student1  23  31
class1  student2  2   9
class1  student2  11  51
class1  student2  60  89
class2  student1  1   2
class2  student1  3   9
```

As my data is large, I want to know if there's a neat way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` parameter, then convert `MultiIndex` to columns with rename index names:

```
df = (pd.concat(dataframe_list, keys=info_list)
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .rename_axis(('class','student'))
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    class   student   A   B
0  class1  student1  10  20
1  class1  student1  23  31
2  class1  student2   2   9
3  class1  student2  11  51
4  class1  student2  60  89
5  class2  student1   1   2
6  class2  student1   3   9
```